# stopping videos from website to play

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, plugins, video-streaming, flash-player

Here is  website from which a lot of videos are being streamed
http://www.jagran.com/spiritual/puja-path-the-veneration-of-saturn-in-the-household-wellbeing-remains-forever-14747757.html?src=fb

I don't want to block flash in my browser is there any other way to block these stream of videos.
Chrome and Windows 8 is what I use.
Suggestions for firefox are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Open the hosts file and add

127.0.0.1  www.jagran.com   to block the domain

[win]+[r]>run (paste=>) C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

- It can open in Notepad or wordpad or ....
- Then File>save and overwrite

  - or save on prompt when closing.

or get addons for selective flash block
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flashcontrol/mfidmkgnfgnkihnjeklbekckimkipmoe?hl=en

Comment: no I just want to block video not the domain